# Filtering records in pyspark dataframe if the struct Array contains a record

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, filter

My Pyspark dataframe looks like this:

```
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- other_attr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I am looking for the rows that don't have [Closed, Yes] in their array of struct under other_attr. The other_attr is an array of struct which could be an empty array. How could I run this filtering?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `array_contains` to check against the struct `[Closed, Yes]` like so

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.show()
# +-----+---------------+
# | name|     other_attr|
# +-----+---------------+
# |test1|[{Closed, Yes}]|
# |test2| [{Closed, No}]|
# |test3|             []|
# +-----+---------------+

(df.where(~F
        .array_contains('other_attr', F.struct(
            F.lit('Closed').alias('key'),
            F.lit('Yes').alias('value'),
        ))
    ).show()
)

# Output
# +-----+--------------+
# | name|    other_attr|
# +-----+--------------+
# |test2|[{Closed, No}]|
# |test3|            []|
# +-----+--------------+
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
I get this error!

Comment: How your code looks like? I tested before posting as an answer, hence the output you above. (Also, IMO, shouldn't you discuss about the error before downvoting someone spending their time answering your question(s)?)

Comment: Sorry for the downvote! I mistakenly voted and wanted to remove the vote and this happen. 
Please edit the code so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_json function with contains to filter rows based on criteria.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.filter(
    ~F.to_json('other_attr').contains(
        F.to_json(
            F.struct(
                F.lit('Closed').alias('key'),
                F.lit('Yes').alias('value')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code it with Spark SQL it is also possible:
Since Spark 2.4.0 **you can use the functions [exist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists)**.

Example with SparkSQL:

```
SELECT
    EXISTS
    (
        ARRAY(named_struct("key": "a", "value": "1"), named_struct("key": "b", "value": "2")),
        x -> x = named_struct("key": "a", "value": "1")
    )
```

Example with PySpark:

```
df.filter('exists(extra_features, x -> x = named_struct("key": "a", "value": "1"))')
```

Note that **not all the functions to manipulate arrays start with array_***.
Ex: [exist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists), [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter), [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size), ...